# Netbeans: Custom HelpCtx that open help in browser

Tags: netbeans-platform, helpcontext

I am trying to read the documentation in Netbeans, but I cannot figure out how to make the help open in the user's browser, instead of having to map help ids to some resources in the project.

I have bean nodes with attribute "propertiesHelpID", which returns a dynamic id based on certain criteria. Let's, for simplicity's sake, just say that one node might return "help.IntegerInputItem" and another "help.StringInputItem"

What I want is that when the user activates the help, it should open the user's browser to: http://somesite.com/wiki/help/IntegerInputItem or http://somesite.com/wiki/help/StringInputItem

How can I make this happen?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. Create a class which inherits from Displayer and uses the ServiceProvider annotation, and go from there...